# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'srcObject')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, simple-peer

I am trying to stream a video, but when i set 'myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream' as in the code below, I recieve an error 'Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'srcObject')'

````js
const myVideo = useRef({});  
const userVideo = useRef({});  
const connectionRef = useRef();  
useEffect(() => {  
  navigator.mediaDevices  
    .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })  
    .then((currentStream) => {  
      setStream(currentStream);  
      myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;  
    });  
  socket.on("me", (id) => {  
    setMe(id);  
  });socket.on("callUser", ({ from, callerName, signal }) => {  
    setCall({ isReceivedCall: true, from, callerName, signal });  
  });  
}, []);```
````

Comment: Please paste your code here, not images.

Answer (score 2):

When using `const myVideo = useRef()`, the value of `myVideo.current` may be `undefined` until the ref has been attached to something.

You may need to check that `myVideo.current` exists before doing any operations on it.

You could do this with `if` statements or [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

#### `if`

```js
if (myVideo.current) {
  // do something
  myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
}
```

#### optional chaining

```js
myVideo.current?.srcObject = currentStream;
```

Both will only execute once the `myVideo.current` has a value

Comment: Yes i tried that code then i executed console.log("Video streaming"), It logged it on the console but the video is not yet streaming

Comment: You may need to execute your code in a `useEffect` hook, if the `currentStream` value changes. I'm not 100% sure if the stream will play immediately without the [autoplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/autoplay) attribute set